# Distribution of the largest eigenvalue of a sample covariance matrix

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

Let $X$ be an $n \times d$ matrix whose rows are normal i.i.d.with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma_d$.

Is there anything we can say on the distribution of the largest eigenvalue of the corresponding sample covariance matrix, that is, the distribution of the largest eigenvalue of $\frac{1}{n}X^TX$?

Comment: The distribution of the sample covariance matrix in the Gaussian case is known as the [Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution). See here for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.3394.pdf for an explicit computation of the PDF of its largest eigenvalue in the $\Sigma_d=I_d$ case. Alternatively, you can prove easier concentration inequalities (see e.g. theorem 6.1 in *High-dimensional statistics: a non-asymptotic viewpoint*).

Comment: @md5 Thanks, but I'm interested in the case for general $\Sigma_d$